# How to create NoSqlEntityManagerFactory properly?

Tags: playorm

I want to user NoSqlEntityManagerFactory create(Map properties) method in Bootstrap class to create a NoSqlEntityManagerFactory. However, I am not sure if I am using the right properties:

```
#nosql.nosqltype=inmemory
nosql.nosqltype=cassandra
nosql.autoCreateKey=create
nosql.cassandra.clusterName=Test cluster
nosql.cassandra.keyspace=dmp_input
nosql.cassandra.seeds=127.0.0.1:9160
```

Should I pass something to nosql.cassandra.builder? This seems to be created by the method, after an astyanax config builder is created... Also, if I pass nosql.autoCreateKey=create, will it create my mapped entities on Cassandra? If I don't want this behavior, should I user nosql.autoCreateKey=none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, those are the correct properties to use.  You only need to pass something to nosql.cassandra.builder IF you want to pass in your own preconfigured astyanax.  Astyanax is HIGHLY configurable so rather than try to program for all options, PlayOrm allows to pass in a few properties and we create it OR you can pass in your own using the other create methods.